# Toggle slide siblings of "this" causing them to bounce open and closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a fairly simple layout of:

```
<div class="faq-wrapper">
  <div class="question">
    Question
  </div>
  <div class="answer">
    Answer
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is repeated for as many questions as are needed. I wanted to create a toggle to show or hide the answer when the question is clicked and this is what I came up with.

```
$('.question').click(function() {

  if($(this).siblings(".answer").is(":visible")) {  
    $(this).siblings(".answer").slideUp("fast");
  }else { 
    $(this).siblings(".answer").slideDown("fast");
  }

});
```

And this works to close open answers (the first one is open by default) but when you click to open one that is hidden it slides open and then immediately slides closed again.

I also tried using the `.slideToggle` method but this made the open ones bounce closed then back open as well.

The jsfiddle I created for my code seems to work how I want it to, so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot what is going on. [jsfiddle.net/Lj2a49a4/6](http://jsfiddle.net/Lj2a49a4/6)

Comment: Post a jsfiddle please.

Comment: Could you check in console, if there is any error

Comment: no errors are in the console.